# Why am I getting a segmentation fault when trimming a string in a recursive function?

Tags: c

I have to implement a function that calculates the hash `h_N` of a string according to a formula `h_0 = 1337`, `h_n = h_n-1 * 5 + c_n`, where `c_1` and `c_n` are the strings characters for my homework.

I thought it would be a great idea to calculate it recursively but unfortunately I get a segmentation fault when trying to remove the last character of my given string.

```c
uint64_t hashString(char *c)
{
    if(strlen(c) == 1) {
        return 1337 * 5 + (int) *c;
    }

    int lc = c[strlen(c) - 1];
    c[strlen(c) - 1] = 0;
    return hashString(c) * 5 + lc;
}
```

I even tried to use `memmove` but it did nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you calling `strlen` so often? It is expensive

Comment: You are calling your function [on a string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/164194/11683)?

Comment: I think you're testing using a string from a read-only memory area. Please share the code that you're using to test your function

Comment: my 2 cents.. using recursion can result in compact, elegant, pretty code. But practically it is dangerous due to stack usage runaway. Unless you **_know_** your function won't recurse an unsafe number of times, it's better to use a looping construct. Hashing certainly isn't a place for recursion, you can hash any amount of data.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I tried to use `memmove(c, c, strlen(c) - 2)` to remove the last char but it did nothing.

Answer (score 3):

> I thought it would be a great idea to calculate it recursively

It isn’t! Unless your compiler can optimize it away (which involves tail call elimination as a step, and your implementation isn’t even tail recursive), each recursive call will use stack space, leading to a stack overflow with relatively small numbers of characters. Your current implementation also

- calls `strlen` several times for every character, which is extremely slow (quadratic time – calculating the hash takes time proportional to the square of the length of the string) unless optimized away by a smart compiler
- mutates its input, which is extremely unusual for a hash

Use a loop instead, and make sure your parameter is a `char const*`.

> ```c
> #include "testlib.h"
> #include "hash.h"
>
> int main() {
>     test_start("hash.c");
>     test_equals_int64(hashString("Abc"), result, "hash of A is correct");
>     return test_end();
> }
> ```

… but in this code, the segfault is specifically caused by the attempted modification of the read-only string literal `"Abc"`. If your compiler didn’t warn you about that, look up how to enable more warnings.

Comment: While all that is true, it doesn't really address the question which was about a segmentation fault.

Comment: @GSerg: “leading to a stack overflow”. I guess it could be caused by something else too.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and it runs fine. But then I am able to crash it too.
i wrote this as main

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[] ) {
   uint64_t ret = hashString( argv[1] );
   return 0;
}
```

If argv[1] is not there, it crashes, otherwise it works fine. So i suspect you have not allocated the memory for char *c. or if it is a string of 0 length.